# How to find similar rows in pyspark dataframe?

Tags: pyspark, similarity

I have a spark dataframe which looks like this:

```
+-------+-----------------------------+
|user_id|       profile_features      |
+-------+-----------------------------+
|   100 |  [0.0,   0.33.., 0.66.., ...|
|   101 |  [0.42..,0.15.., 0.57.., ...|
|   102 |  [0.33..,0.0,    0.25.., ...|
|   103 |  [0.15..,0.33.., 0.15.., ...|
|   104 |  [0.0,   0.0,    0.33.., ...|
+-------+-----------------------------+
```

How to find most similar users to a given user by their user_id?
I am thinking about multiplying a given user_id with other rows(user_ids) to find their similarity, then somehow sort out resulting table and return topmost N user_ids. If it is the right way, how to implement it in pyspark?

Answer (score 0):

Pass the columns you want to find duplicates in attributes and do groupby taking count if count greater than 1 then its duplicate otherwise unique records/

```
Attribute1 = ["user_id","profile_features"]

Selected_Col_Groupby = Data.select(Attribute1).groupBy(Attribute1).count()

Rule_Flag = Selected_Col_Groupby.withColumn('RuleCol', f.when(Selected_Col_Groupby["count"] > 1, 1).otherwise(0)).drop("count")

Duplicates = Rule_Flag.filter('RuleCol'+" == 1")
Not_Duplicates = Rule_Flag.filter('RuleCol'+" == 0")
```